# Format date in a specific way

Tags: bash, date, unix

I need to get date in the following format for use in a bash script: year month day hour minute second. The time should be in 24 hour format.

```
eg 20160330141355
```

What is the correct way to print out a date in a specific format?

Comment: So where is the problem?

Comment: [man date](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
a=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

The UNIX `date` command is what you want: `date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`